# Put elements of similar type together

Tags: algorithm

I read this interview question somewhere and was trying to solve it:

Given a fruit stall (at max 8 different types of fruits). Put fruits of similar types together.
Restrictions: a)  Fruit Stall is your entire world (i.e. dont use extra space),  b) Taking a fruit and knowing its type (getType()) is a costly operation but swapping is a very cheap operation.

Note: You need to write a code to handle all cases keeping in mind the max types of fruit can be 8.

So, the idea which pops in my mind is, we need to call getType() for all the fruits(array elements) and then sort them accordingly based on a particular type. I am not able to get how swapping can be done here without knowing the Type of the fruit and what can be the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an interview question, I'm going to assume that your fruit stall is an array. Divide the array into eight regions, so that each region contains only fruit of a given type, using seven pointers, one to the start of each region except the first. Use an eighth pointer to point at the start of the unsorted area.

Initialize the pointers to point at the start of the array. Getting the definition of the pointers is tricky because you have to cover cases where there are no fruits of a given type. One possible definition is that Pointer i contains the number of fruits sorted so far of types up to and including i, for i = 1..8. Then at the beginning all the pointers are set equal to zero and 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 | corresponds to p1=3 p2=5 p3=6 p4=8 p5=p6=p7=p8=8

Repeatedly look at the first fruit at the start of the unsorted region to find out its type. If it should not go in the final region swap it with the element at the start of the final region and advance the pointer to the start of the final region. If it should not go in the second last region swap it with the element at the start of the second last region and advance the pointer to the start of the second last region... and so on until the new fruit is in its correct place. Now advance the pointer to the first unsorted fruit and repeat.

This looks at each fruit once, and I don't think you can sort with fewer calls to getType(). You don't care about the number of swaps, so I think this is optimal.

I will put in lines showing the swaps starting with c1,c2,c1,c3,c2,c1,c4,c4. I won't bother to write in the cs and I will use a | to divide the region on the left where everything is known to be in order from the region on the right where the types are unknown

| 1 2 1 3 2 1 4 4

1 | 2 1 3 2 1 4 4

1 2 | 1 3 2 1 4 4

1 1 | 2 3 2 1 4 4

1 1 2 | 3 2 1 4 4

1 1 2 3 | 2 1 4 4

1 1 2 2 | 3 1 4 4

1 1 2 2 3 | 1 4 4

1 1 2 2 1 | 3 4 4

1 1 1 2 2 | 3 4 4

1 1 1 2 2 3 | 4 4

1 1 1 2 2 3 4 | 4

1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 |

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I am unable to understand few things here. Let us suppose we have the below array: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} where types are like {c1,c2,c1,c3,c2,c1,c4,c4} So, you mean i need to have 7 different pointers say (p1-p7) pointing to arr[1] to arr[7]. Where should the final pointer p8 be pointing to? Also, can you please explain with this example the following : " If it should not go in the final region swap it with the element at the start of the final region and advance the pointer to the start of the final region.".

Comment: I have worked through your example so you can see what gets swapped where. The first seven pointers show you where the boundaries between the areas for different types are in the section you have ordered so far. The eighth pointer shows where the boundary between ordered and unordered data is. The details of the definitions of the pointers depend on exactly how you write the code.

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This can most likely be done as an in place merge sort. As you mentioned check the type of each fruit immediately. This wont use up any extra memory (many guides on how to do an in place merge sort) will only call getType() once, and will result in `nlog(n)` run time with `n` memory usage.

Is there any info we know right off the bat? It seems like the question is worded in such a way that they would normally give us an alternative way to avoid having to make the `getType()` call n times. If this is an in person interview question don't be surprised if the goal of this exercise is supposed to evolve as the interviewer starts going into it. This would explain why they specifically mention the `getType()` as being expensive

Comment: Yes, it was an in-person interview question and the expected complexity as told by him was O(n).